# Extracting drawings data from models in BIM360 through Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am looking for a solution to extract drawings information (such as drawing, title, revision etc.) from multiple Revit models accommodated in BIM360.
I assume that Forge API can be helpful on this point, yet I am still trying to figure out where to start from.

In addition, my current team's technical abilities are limited to a good level of Dynamo and Python.
What would be your suggestion in terms of overall workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Forge) can help with this. For example, you could use the [Data Management API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/overview/) to programatically browse through existing designs in BIM360, and the [Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) to access all the information that was extracted from these designs (3D views, 2D sheets, metadata, etc.). This tutorial could be a good starting point: https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/.

However, keep in mind that APS is a cloud **development** platform, meaning that some basic understanding of web/server development is expected.